# Setting GPIO value on boot

Tags: gpio, boot

I'm a semi-linux newcomer and i have a question:

I need to set some GPIO pins in this way: (pin 18 out, pin 17 in)
(actually i'm doing this via WiringPi(pyton) trought this commands)

```
gpio export 18 out

gpio export 17 in
```

All Works fine if i run these commands via terminal.
However i have set these commands in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

before `exit 0`

to run it at boot, but after some tryies it won't work.
It could be a path problem?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks mboy.

Comment: Path thing - yes, better fix it to using full path. What happens when you run /etc/rc.local - are you getting any output, is the script runnable?

Comment: Ok, but i'dont know how to set full path.. it's the first time that i use rc.local and wiringpi..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've fixed it!
All i needed is to set full path. In my case `/usr/local/bin/gpio export 18 out`
because gpio is a third party command.

Answer (score 2):

Another good idea is to create your own script like:

`#! /bin/bash 
gpio mode 18 out
gpio mode 17 in
exit 0`

Save it to file e.g. `gpio_init.sh`

Run `chmod a+x simple_bash.sh`  to make it executable

Copy to `init.d` with: `sudo cp /path_to_script/script.sh /etc/init.d/`

Add to boot sequence: `sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition for Andrey Volkov's answer, new Debian system has a set format for the init script. Please refers to [here](https://gist.github.com/miromannino/a17f3e6f3fdcb4d94a1f)

With that I have made a script that should work on your system.

Name the following script gpio_init and chown to root.root and chmod to 755. Copy it to /etc/init.d/

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          gpio_init
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       Initialize GPIO pins for the project
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/gpio-init
RUNAS=root

PIDFILE=/var/run/gpio_init.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/gpio_init.log

start() {
  if [ -f /var/run/$PIDNAME ] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/$PIDNAME); then
    echo 'Service already running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Starting service…' >&2
  local CMD="$SCRIPT &> \"$LOGFILE\" & echo \$!"
  su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS > "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service started' >&2
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    echo 'Service not running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Stopping service…' >&2
  kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service stopped' >&2
}

uninstall() {
  echo -n "Are you really sure you want to uninstall this service? That cannot be undone. [yes|No] "
  local SURE
  read SURE
  if [ "$SURE" = "yes" ]; then
    stop
    rm -f "$PIDFILE"
    echo "Notice: log file is not be removed: '$LOGFILE'" >&2
    update-rc.d -f gpio_init remove
    rm -fv "$0"
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  uninstall)
    uninstall
    ;;
  retart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|uninstall}"
esac
```

This script will call another script under /usr/local/bin/

gpio-init (sorry about the naming here...

```
#! /bin/bash

function cleanup {
    echo 5 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
    echo 6 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
    exit 0
}

# Clean up when exit
trap cleanup EXIT
trap cleanup SIGHUP
trap cleanup SIGQUIT
trap cleanup SIGINT
trap cleanup SIGTERM

echo 5 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio5/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value
sleep 0.000030  # 30us
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value
sleep 0.000030  # 30us
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value
sleep 0.001

echo 6 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio6/direction
echo "rising" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio6/edge

sleep infinity

exit 0
```

A couple of things here. First I use echo GPIO_PIN > /sys/class/gpio/export for exporting the pin, similarly for setting up IN/OUT 1/0 INTERRUPT edge. You can customize it according to your need.

I use `sleep infinity` to let it run forever

I capture any interrupt signals and do a clean up function where I unexported the GPIO PINS.

Again made this script only writable to root (for security reason) and put it under /usr/loca/bin

Test with `sudo /etc/init.d/gpio_init start`
And `sudo /etc/init.d/gpio_init stop`

And once ready use `sudo update-rc.d gpio-init defaults` to run the script at start up

Comment: Might work for anyone running an obsolete SysV OS, but hardly relevant.